# Responsive Website CSS not loading over Barracuda SSL VPN

Tags: web-services, twitter-bootstrap, ssl, vpn

Responsive Website CSS not loading over Barracuda SSL VPN

Not really sure what to do. It just straight up 404's on the CSS files.

I'm using Twitter Bootstrap 3.1.1 and jQuery 1.11 on the website.

Comment: Maybe you should display some of your code. Maybe the relevant <head> part showing your files paths etc. Hard for anyone to help with just the info you've supplied.

Answer (score 0):

As Billy says it's hard to tell without more details (and possibly a sample of the code), but it sounds like you're using the path-based reverse proxy option described on this webpage - [Barracuda SSL VPN TechLibrary](https://techlib.barracuda.com/SSLVPN/CustomWebFwds) - and you haven't set up the paths correctly.

The reverse proxy engine on the SSL VPN will try and rewrite links as necessary when it sees links to other locations on the same server, but as with any automated process it's not infallible. You may find that adding the paths to the CSS files into the "Paths:" part of the Web Forward config will fix your issue.

There are also four exceptions for paths noted on the Techlib which are used internally on the SSL VPN for loading UI components and therefore aren't available for use within a Web Forward.

```
/default/
/theme/
/js/
/fs/
```

If you still can't get it going, then open a case with Support and they'll be able to go through some more specific troubleshooting with you, contact details for various regions are on this webpage - [Barracuda Support](https://www.barracuda.com/support)